# Etherli wallet problems

Tags: transactions, accounts, ether-li

My Etherli wallet has a huge problem. When I try to send Ether with it, I always get the message:

> Error: invalid rlp: total length is larger than the data

I have no idea what that means or what to do. If anybody can help me to solve this problem, I guarantee a huge surprise gift. Of course the gift has to do with Ethereum :-)

Comment: Somehow not.. transactions are pending..
i just get an "request initiated" and nothing happens.
Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It was my Internet browser version causing the problem. Use an older browser, newer ones don't interface well. that should do the trick.

Comment: Welcome to the community!  Advertising is frowned upon, so best to put your address in your profile.  I suggest editing your answer and I'll clean up this comment.